# MATLAB indices of minimum meeting a specific criteria

Tags: matlab

Say I have a matrix

```
A= [1 2 3
    2 5 5
    4 6 2]
```

I want to find the indices of the maximum from a specific range of columns, given by a vector `A_index =[1 0 1]` meaning find the maximum from columns 1 and 3. This maximum is 5 . How do I find its indices , i.e., row =2 column = 3. Note that 5 also occurs in column 2 but I do not want it
If I use a plain "`find`" , I do not get the correct solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace elements of undesirable columns of `A` with `NaN`. Then use [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) to find the linear index of the maximum element. Finally convert the linear index to row and column subscripts using [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html).

```
A_index(A_index==0)=NaN; %Replacing 0s with NaNs (needed when A has non-positive elements)
A = bsxfun(@times, A, A_index); %With this, zeros (now NaNs) of A won't affect 'max'
[~ , ind] = max(A(:));          %finding the linear index of the maximum value
[r, c] = ind2sub(size(A),ind);  %converting the linear index to row and column subscripts
```

---

In ≥ R2016b, the second line can be written with implicit expansion as:

```
A = A.*A_index;
```

The last two lines can also be written as:

```
[r,c] = find(A==max(A(:)));
```

whichever you find better.